# How to manage database server and web server through plesk panel

Tags: sql-server, database, plesk

I have a dedicated server with SQL Server & IIS (web server). I am using Plesk control panel
to manage everything. I plan to move the SQL Server to another machine.

But I need to manage through Plesk panel only.

Anyone please help me to resolve this issue. whether it is possible or not.

Comment: Ask your web hosting provider for help and documentation, or check the Plesk web site for additional documentation / tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After moving your SQL server you can just change IP address of this SQL server in Plesk:

Tools & Settings > Database Servers > click on you SQL server > Settings > change "Host name or IP address" to your new IP/hostname address

After this, you should check DB creation and backup operations of subscription with SQL databases, because Plesk has another logic of operation with remote DB servers.